# $scope is not accessible from callback function after following Google docs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-cloud-endpoints

I have followed the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications/) (scroll down) for bootstrapping AngularJS with Cloud Endpoints. My code looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="AnimalsApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Animal Manager Server</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/animal.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
    {{message}} world
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**animal.js**

```
angular.module('AnimalsApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello';  
    $window.init = function() {
      $scope.$apply($scope.load_guestbook_lib);
    };
    $scope.load_guestbook_lib = function() {
      gapi.client.load('creatureCloud', 'v1', function() {
        $scope.is_backend_ready = true;
        $scope.message = 'Hello beautiful';  
        console.log('Made it!');
      }, 'http://localhost:8888/_ah/api');
    };
  }]);

function init() {
  window.init();
}
```

The text `Made it!` is shown in the console log, demonstrating that the callback was executed. However, setting `$scope.is_backend_ready = true` has no effect on showing `<div id="listResult" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">`. This leads me to believe that the `$scope` object in the callback is not working correctly.

What have I done wrong? Are the Google docs wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intention of using `$scope.$apply()` is correct but it is in the wrong place. You need to do it in the callback not out of it. With the way you have you are executing the function `load_guestbook_lib` and then performing a digest cycle. Since the `gapi.client.load` function is async it runs later and no digest happens as it happens out of angular context.

Try:

```
$window.init = function() {
  $scope.load_guestbook_lib(); //Just invoke the function
};
$scope.load_guestbook_lib = function() {
  gapi.client.load('creatureCloud', 'v1', function() {
    $scope.is_backend_ready = true;
    $scope.message = 'Hello cats';  
    console.log('Made it!');
    $scope.$apply(); //<-- Apply here
  }, 'http://localhost:8888/_ah/api');
};
```